# Difference between value === expression and expression === value?

Tags: javascript, php, conditional-statements

In many place, I've seen that there is used the expression `if (value === expression)` rather than `if (expression === value)`.

For example, In *php* we use-

```php
if (false === strpos('abc', 'a'))
```

And also I see after minifying JavaScript, the minified file also generated like this.

So my question is, what is the benefit of `value === expression` over `expression === value`?

**Note: This question may be redundant but I may not get the proper keywords for searching. If it is duplicated then I am ready to close the question.**

Comment: You may be looking for [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). It makes no difference.

Comment: The only disadvantage of `value === expression` is that it upsets me on a deep level when I have to read it :)

Comment: @ChrisG You misspelled "advantage" >:)

Comment: @elclanrs maybe I am looking for this. Could you please write a clear answer for future reference with pros, and cons (if any).

Comment: This (AFAIK) was a result of mistakes writing `$a = false` which would assign a value, `false = $a` on the other hand is an error.

Comment: There's also an [eslint yoda rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/yoda) for this. Pro is that you cannot mistakenly assign (`=`) in the comparison, con is the worse readability

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a difference because the idea of equality operator is that to check if both sides are have the same value, in `===` also same type.

Comment: May have any architectural benefits.